# how to trigger event in case of href which calls div panel

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/BRSaG/396/

when i click on the **leftpanel2** , i am caling a div panel with id **leftpanel2**.

My requirement is that :

I have got an another href tag **leftpanel3** and when i click on that , how can i trigger an event so that  it calls **leftpanel2** (similar behaviour as clicked on **leftpanel2**)

http://jsfiddle.net/BRSaG/396/

My code

```
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
<a href="#leftpanel2">Open panel</a>
      <h1>Open Panel Header</h1>    

        <a href="#leftpanel3">second panel</a>
      <h1>Second Open panel</h1>    

    </div>
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <div data-role="panel" id="leftpanel2" data-position="left" data-display="push" data-dismissible="true" data-theme="a" class="ui-panel ui-panel-position-left ui-panel-display-push ui-body-a ui-panel-animate ui-panel-open">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Could you please let me know how to do this ??

Comment: why not just use same href on both? - gives you the functionality you're after. I mean - as far as i understand your question - you want both buttons to open the same div. - correct?

Comment: Use attribute selector and trigger the event on first button. Check my answer for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you achieve that:

Here I've used attribute selector and triggered the click event on first button link.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href=#leftpanel3]', function(event) {
        $("a[href=#leftpanel2]").trigger("click");
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a0d7bjLp/)**